# remove bounding boxes inside bounding boxes for number recognition

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying a number recognition. However after contour finding. I get bounding boxes inside the main bounding box for numbers 0,6,8 ... as shown in figure. Please help me with this initial step of image processing.
I have tried using group rectangles but they are not working. Please check the code below. Thank you.

Image: http://tinypic.com/r/1twx05/5

```
int main()
{
    Mat inimage, gray;
    inimage = imread("sample.jpg");
    cvtColor(inimage, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    GaussianBlur(gray, gray, Size(5,5), 0);
    adaptiveThreshold(gray, gray, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 0);
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours( gray, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

    vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
    vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );

    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
    {
        approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
        boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
    }
    //groupRectangles(boundRect, 1, 0.2);
    Scalar color = Scalar(0,0,255);
    for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {
        //drawContours( inimage, contours_poly, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
        rectangle( inimage, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 1, 8, 0 );
    }
    namedWindow( "Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Contours", inimage );
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the flag: `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL` instead of `CV_RETR_TREE`

as stated in the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#void%20findContours%28InputOutputArray%20image,%20OutputArrayOfArrays%20contours,%20OutputArray%20hierarchy,%20int%20mode,%20int%20method,%20Point%20offset%29) it tells to take only outer contours.

Or follow the tree hierarchy to drop nested contours (read the docs for how-to)